# Is iTunes 12.4.1 available for 32-bit Windows?

Tags: itunes, windows, 32-bit

I couldn't find it on the Apple website, I was only offered the 64-bit version. Maybe that's because I'm using a 64-bit client for the download?

Comment: [It should support 32-bit](https://support.apple.com/kb/DL1814?locale=en_US), but I'm not sure why you'd want it, and it isn't happy about giving me the download either.

Comment: @JMY1000 The reason I need 32-bit is because I intend to run it under Wine on Linux, and 64-bit is not supported.

Comment: Also, the 32 bit version purportedly won't run on 64-bit Windows, not sure why.

Comment: Difficult question, might be better on askubuntu.com.

Comment: @JMY1000 I'm not asking how to run iTunes under Wine. I already know how to do that. I'm asking how to download the 32-bit version. That question has nothing to do with Ubuntu, and would be off-topic at AU.

Comment: Fair enough. Figured it out: you have to pretend you're 32-bit Windows. Posting answer now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you make the [iTunes download](http://www.apple.com/itunes/download/) believe you are 32-bit Windows, it will provide you with the 32-bit installer.

Change the user agent string following instructions for your browser (this [guide](https://www.maketecheasier.com/change-browser-user-agents/) seems to work) to something like `Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; Win32, x86; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko` so it appears you are running 32-bit Windows. Visit the download page again: it should now give you iTunesSetup.exe instead of iTunes64Setup.exe.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I'll just use a 32-bit Virtual Machine.

Comment: @Fiksdal That works too :)